# AppleScript get active Application

Tags: macos, mac

How might I run code(for example `display dialog("test")`) using AppleScript only if the "Finder" Application is currently in focus/active.

Comment: Um, if the application is already active, what do you aim to accomplish by activating it again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718520/how-do-i-write-applescript-that-will-give-me-an-hourly-popup-alert idle is relevant although doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. The script in my answer works, for a given definition of 'works' i.e. it reports accurately whether or not Finder is frontmost.

Comment: @Tetsujin updated

Comment: How are you going to be launching the Applescript app? Double clicking it will, of course, always show the Finder as the '2nd to last' frontmost. Changing answer - this will work if called from Script Editor, but 'fails' if double-clicked in Finder, as it gives a false-positive

Comment: @Tetsujin That's the issue I'm running in to.

Comment: Can I ask *why* you need to periodically check if the Finder is/was frontmost? It would seem to be a whole lot easier to just fire an Applescript to bring it to the front & quit… or just click on it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I would like an icon on the dock that does a "PageDown" when clicked on.  `key code (insert code here)` works but you can't know ahead of time what application is focused.

Comment: @Tetsujin You have put forth enough effort.  I'm convinced what I'm after is possible in AppleScript.

Comment: tell application "whichever" to activate \n tell application "System Events" to key code… end tell etc... & ty for the points on the Answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's the point I don't what application it is.  I would the PageDown icon to work in any application.

Comment: then all you need is to tell application secondFrontmost… Whichever it is, as my Applescript will have backgrounded

Comment: @Tetsujin There appears to be no way to get the secondfrontmost application.  Same issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411174/applescript-open-frontmost-file-with-another-application

Comment: my answer already finds the second frontmost, by virtue of itself being frontmost, then hiding. There is no programmatic way to interrogate the launch services to extract that information. Best you can do is by launch order. If all you need is a Page Down button press, why not look at the other myriad ways that can be achieved?

Comment: @Tetsujin question accepted http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173298/dock-icon-that-activates-pagedown?noredirect=1#comment203832_173298

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will work if the script is called from Script Editor, as it 'gets out of the way' to check the next app in line, but will fail if double clicked from Finder, as Finder will then always be last in line.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostProcess to first process where it is frontmost
    set visible of frontmostProcess to false
    repeat while (frontmostProcess is frontmost)
        delay 0.2
    end repeat
    set secondFrontmost to name of first process where it is frontmost
    set frontmost of frontmostProcess to true
end tell

tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    if "Finder" is in secondFrontmost then
        display dialog ("Finder was last in front")
    else
        display dialog (secondFrontmost & " was last in front")
    end if
end tell
```

---

*<sub>Leaving previous answer here for posterity</sub>*

Rejigged entire answer after having not read the question properly initially ;-)

```
tell application "System Events"
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
    if "Finder" is in activeApp then
        display dialog ("test")
    else
        display dialog ("test2")
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: +1 Although your proposed solution doesn't seem to work as is.  I get "test" as long as the application is open and not necessarily if it is active or not.

Comment: a rethink… edited answer

Comment: complete rewrite, now I'm back at my desktop - this now does exactly what you asked.

Comment: Hmm..  If I add the applescript as an app to to the dock it only displays "test2" no matter what application I have originally focused.

Comment: probably because the Applescript app is frontmost. Test by adding a 3s delay, then clicking the desktop between launch & trigger [that's how I tested it here]

Comment: you can also replace the second dialog command with `display dialog (activeApp)` to confirm exactly what the script thinks is the frontmost.

Comment: Be careful with this -- some apps's app names (e.g., `tell application "app_name"`) differ from their process names (e.g., `set frontmost of process "app_process" to true`).

Comment: Also, be careful if you have different versions of the same app installed (e.g. Firefox)! It may (probably will) launch the wrong one.

Comment: Still works in 2019 on Mojave