# Dock Icon that activates PageDown

Tags: macos, pages

Is it possible to create a mac OSX dock icon that activates the page down key?

Comment: May I ask why you would need such a thing?

Comment: @markhunte There is no pagedown key and I don't like the fn+down arrow key shorcut.  It is to difficult to reach.

Comment: You tried Option + down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmostProcess to first process where it is frontmost
    delay 0.01
    key code 121
end tell
```

116 is `key code` for page up.  Here's a list of the other key codes: [Key Codes for Function and Special Keys in Applescript](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html)